# Inserting progressbar on button click

Tags: android, xml

I have this XML and I'm planning that when the login button is clicked, it disappears and the progress bar shows up. how can I do it? this is the image of the XML already made. I've tried dozen of layout edits but still cannot achieve such. I hope someone could help as soon as possible. If there are any suggestions that you can tell please do help.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/logregbackground"
    tools:context=".Login.LoginRegister">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainformBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/darkbackground" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/isalonlogowithoutbackground"
        android:id="@+id/mainformLogo"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"

        />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollviewid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainformLogo"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/trans_white_rectangle"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"

            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Welcome to iSalon"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Style on the go, Wherever you go"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp" />
                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:hint="Email/Username"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_user_icon"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/loginUser"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_pass_icon"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/loginPass"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/login_button"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loadinglogin"
                android:layout_width="124dp"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:background="@color/white" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonRegister"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Register"
                android:background="@drawable/register_button"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: The XML output]

Comment: What code have you used to try to get the login button to disappear and the progress bar to appear?

Comment: their visibility sir. its on the onclick of the button when pressed. its
 loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
login.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: please post your activity code also, that will help to identify your problem faster.

Comment: the problem was solved sir. just put on visibility gone and put the same height and paddings and margins that I had with the button same for the progressbar. Thanks for the help sirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the progress bar to be visible at first, you need to give it a "gone" visibility attribute in the layout (or in your onCreate code):

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

That would explain why your progress bar is visible before the login button is clicked.

If your login button isn't disappearing when it's clicked, I don't know why. You'd probably have to show your code.

Comment: I did that sir to show where the progressbar is lined up. I have put in my onclick of the login button that when it is clicked it would disappear and the progressbar shows.

Comment: @Denscottie You did what? removed the `android:visibility="gone"` from the progress bar in the layout XML that you posted? If so, please post your actual layout XML, so that we're not trying to debug something that isn't your problem. Also post your complete onClick code.

Comment: OH so when I have put the same height and width of the progressbar then make it gone and when clicked visible, does it compensate the buttons space? I think im getting to the point!

Comment: problem was solved sir. just the visibility gone and setting up the same margin and paddings as well as height and width of the progressbar to the button. Thank you so much.